# expressionengine conditional

Tags: expressionengine

I have a simple plugin that outputs a number using `{exp:number}`. How can I use this in a conditional. like

```
{if {exp:number} > 2} Greater then two {/if}
```

I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't written a plugin but whenever I've seen them used as a conditional they are enclosed in quotation marks:

```
{if "{exp:my_plugin:correct_answer question='{question}'}"}Congratulations!{/if}
```

I'm not sure how you apply this to magnitude comparisons, but you might find more help on this thread in the EE forums:

http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/194654/#918764